# No tooltip on search results page on careers.stackoverflow Mail Sent icon

Tags: feature-request, jobs

As petty as this sounds, performing a search on careers.stackoverflow.com returns a list of jobs, with a star icon for favourite, which has a tooltip.

But if you've applied for a job, the icon (icon-mail-sent.png) is also shown below the star, but it has no tooltip!